# Permissions on UserActivity search api

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have been attempting to test the UserActivity.Search api using the online tool:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

This returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The account I'm using is the master account which has all permissions checked (although I get the same response with the service account I'm using to call the api programatically). Can anyone suggest what permissions I might be missing or how to add them please?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question but it might help other people. A typo in the ViewId produces a permissions error so it's worth checking parameters *carefully*